LM Studio - Failed to load model
I get this error message when loading the model in LM Studio 0.2.31:
Model: stable-diffusion-v1-5-pruned-emaonly-f32.gguf
Error:
"llama.cpp error: 'invalid model: tensor 'cond_stage_model.transformer.text_model.encoder.layers.0.layer_' is duplicated'"
json
{
 "title": "Failed to load model",
 "cause": "llama.cpp error: 'invalid model: tensor 'cond_stage_model.transformer.text_model.encoder.layers.0.layer_' is duplicated'",
 "errorData": {
 "n_ctx": 2048,
 "n_batch": 512,
 "n_gpu_layers": 20
 },
 "data": {
 "memory": {
 "ram_capacity": "31.91 GB",
 "ram_unused": "14.17 GB"
 },
 "gpu": {
 "gpu_names": [
 "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070"
 ],
 "vram_recommended_capacity": "11.99 GB",
 "vram_unused": "10.85 GB"
 },
 "os": {
 "platform": "win32",
 "version": "10.0.22631"
 },
 "app": {
 "version": "0.2.31",
 "downloadsDir": "C:\\Users\\barba\\.cache\\lm-studio\\models"
 },
 "model": {}
 }
}

How can I solve this problem?

Unfortunately I don't think you can solve this as I believe LM Studio does not support any text-to-image LLMs.
